# Jquery method doesn't work on dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a price list and validate its values.

This is my function:

```js
(function($) {
        $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
            return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
                if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
                    this.oldValue = this.value;
                    this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
                    this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
                } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
                    this.value = this.oldValue;
                    this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
                } else {
                    this.value = "";
                }
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));


    // Para números enteros
    $(".intTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
        return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="intTextBox" id="intTextBox">
```

This works fine.

But when I insert elements dynamically the method doesn't work.

```js
(function($) {
        $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
            return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
                if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
                    this.oldValue = this.value;
                    this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
                    this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
                } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
                    this.value = this.oldValue;
                    this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
                } else {
                    this.value = "";
                }
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));


    // Para números enteros
    $(".intTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
        return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
    });
    
    $('#add').click(function(e){
      $('#generate').append('<input id="intTextBox" class="intTextBox">');
    }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<div id="generate">
  <input id="intTextBox" class="intTextBox">
</div>
```

how could i solve this? I've been looking all morning, thanks for reading.(I have more validation methods, this is a small summary).

Comment: You would need to reapply the input filter after you add the new element. Also, you really should not be creating multiple elements in the same page that have the same ID.

Comment: You call a person's name. They are not in the room. Nothing happens. They walk into the room. You expect that person to know they have been called. That does not happen! You have to initialize it after the element has been added to the page.

Comment: thanks for your reply, how can i do that?

Comment: You reference the new element and call the method on it...

Answer (score 0):

append DOM elements with already connected validation methods

```
    $('#add').click(function(e){
      $('#generate').append('<input id="intTextBox" 
        class="intTextBox">').inputFilter(function(value) {
         return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
        });
      }
    );
```

Comment: Not going to work, you are attaching it to generate element, not the input

Answer (score 0):

When you reference an element, it does not keep looking for new elements that are added after the code runs. So it will not locate dynamically created inputs.

You need to create the element and use inputFilter on that element.

```
$(".intTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
    return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
});

$('#add').click(function(e){
  var newInput = $('<input name="intTextBox" class="intTextBox">');
  newInput.inputFilter(function(value) {
    return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
  });
  $('#generate').append(newInput);
}
```

to remove the code duplication

```
function addFilter (elems) {
  elems.inputFilter(function(value) {
    return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
  });
}

addFilter($(".intTextBox"));

$('#add').click(function(e){
  var newInput = $('<input name="intTextBox" class="intTextBox">');
  addFilter(newInput);
  $('#generate').append(newInput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works for me. If I could give you votes in favor, I would give them.

Comment: So mark it as the answer @JhonMaldonado if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code below randomizes your ID for the new element to avoid conflict (not a perfect solution; just a hacky work-around for the example), and then applies the filter on the new element.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      } else {
        this.value = "";
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

// Para números enteros
$(".intTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
});

$('#add').click(function(e) {
  let randomId = "intTextBox_" + getRandomInt(100000);
  $('#generate').append(`<input id="${randomId}" class="intTextBox">`);
  $(`#${randomId}`).inputFilter(function(value) {
    return /^-?\d*$/.test(value);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<div id="generate">
  <input id="intTextBox" class="intTextBox">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code can still make two random numbers that are the same. ;)

Comment: For sure. I wasn't implying it was a permanent solution for the ID issue; just making it likely to avoid conflict for the example.  But on the first click, there's a 1 in 100000 chance the ID won't be unique :). I updated the answer to indicate that it's a work-around for the example, and not a final solution to that particular concern.